# Most efficient way to get rid of duplicates in excel table that still have unique values behind them?

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have a table with of over 111000 rows extracted from a separate database. The first column has a product code, the second column has another identifying code, but the third column has a unique URL.
The problem is that most products have multiple URLs. This creates a table with duplicate codes, but with unique URLs. To maybe better illustrate it:

| SKU | EAN | URL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `ZA123` | `004998` | https://example.com/A1_Afb_01 |
| `ZA123` | `004998` | https://example.com/A1_Afb_02 |
| `ZA123` | `004998` | https://example.com/A1_Afb_03 |
| `FA156` | `#N/A` | https://example.com/A9_Afb_01 |
| `GD222` | `016847` | https://example.com/Z1_Afb_01 |
| `GD222` | `016847` | https://example.com/Z1_Afb_02 |

What I want to do is put each URL that belongs to a code, in a column behind it. So I would create URL 1, URL 2, etc. (up to URL 20, as that is the maximum amount of pictures a product has).

Doing this manually would take way too long, and my attempts at doing it with formula have also ended in failure, as Excel keeps crashing (likely due to the fact that it has to make too many calculations one after another).

So is there anyone who might know a more effective way to do this? A way that doesn't crash Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

**M Code**

```
let

//ensure table name in next line matches real table name in workbook
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//set all data types to Text
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"SKU", type text}, {"EAN", type text}, {"URL", type text}}),

//Replace error cells
    #"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Changed Type", {{"EAN", null}}),

//Group by SKU/EAN and create List of URLs
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Replaced Errors", {"SKU", "EAN"}, {
        {"URL", each [URL], type list}        
        }),

//How many columns for the URL split
    numCols = List.Max(List.Transform(#"Grouped Rows"[URL], each List.Count(_))),

//convert List into delimited string
//then expand into columns
//Note that we use # for the delimiter since it is invalid within a URL
expand = Table.SplitColumn(
            Table.TransformColumns(#"Grouped Rows", {"URL", each Text.Combine(_,"#")}),
            "URL",
            Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("#"), numCols)
in 
    expand
```

**Original**
[image]

**Results**
[image]

Comment: This did exactly what I needed! Thank you very much! Looks like Excel still has many capabilities that I need to discover and learn to use.

Answer (score 0):

you should write a script(with python or PowerShell) first because the way that script execute would be much more controllable than the excel formula which is not optimized for this stuff and even maybe has the worst performance.